# Possible to give a type to fold_left() using Mypy?

Tags: python, mypy

I've got a simple left fold function, as follows:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Callable, Optional, TypeVar, overload


S = TypeVar("S")
T = TypeVar("T")


def fold_left(it: Iterable[S], f: Callable[[T, S], T], init: Optional[T] = None) -> T:
    it = iter(it)

    if init is None:
        try:
            acc = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise ValueError("fold_left given empty iterable with no init")
    else:
        acc = init

    for i in it:
        acc = f(acc, i)

    return acc
```

Mypy throws the following errors when checking that code:

```
10: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "T", variable has type "S")
13: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "T", variable has type "S")
13: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "S"; expected "T"
15: error: Incompatible return value type (got "S", expected "T")
```

It appears that Mypy doesn't like the fact that -- when `init is None` -- the types S and T will be the same. Is there some way to finagle the code such that it'll type check properly?

I tried overloading using the following lines, to no effect:

```py
@overload
def fold_left(it: Iterable[S], f: Callable[[T, S], T], init: T) -> T:
    ...


@overload
def fold_left(it: Iterable[S], f: Callable[[S, S], S]) -> S:
    ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't `acc` (type `T`) be the same type as values in `it` (type `Iterable[S]`), regardless? For instance, `fold_left([1,2,3,4], add)` would return a value of type `int`, and `[1,2,3,4]` is an iterable containing values of type `int`, meaning in a lot of cases `T` and `S` are the same type.

Comment: `acc` is only of type `S` when `init` isn't specified. If `init` is specified, `acc` could be a different type. Consider the following line, where `it` is of type `List[int]` and `acc` is of type `str`: `fold_left([1, 2, 3], lambda x, y: x + str(y), "")  # => '123'`

Comment: Overloading is IMO the way to go. What's the issue with that?

Comment: Note that ``mypy`` *cannot* assume that ``T`` and ``S`` are the same. Static typing means the code must be correct for *all* ``T``, ``S`` (*including* those for which ``T != S``), not for *any* ``T``, ``S`` (*excluding* those for which ``T != S``). The function itself must be well-typed, regardless of some concrete, dynamic ``f`` or ``init``  values restricting it to valid behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question.

First, there is the type checking of the external interface of your function. This is where `overload` is relevant.

```py
@overload
def fold_left(it: Iterable[S], f: Callable[[T, S], T], init: T) -> T:
    ...


@overload
def fold_left(it: Iterable[S], f: Callable[[S, S], S]) -> S:
    ...
```

This specifies all valid signatures of your function.

But this doesn't (directly) help with the type checking of our function. We need to fix that independently.

```
def fold_left(it: Iterable[S], f: Callable[[T, S], T], init: Optional[T] = None) -> T:
    # we can't change the type of it which is already defined to be an 
    # `Iterable`, so in order for `next` to type check we need a new 
    # variable of type `Iterator` 
    itor: Iterator[S] = iter(it) 

    # acc contains or return value it therefore has to be of type `T`
    acc: T

    if init is None:
        try:
            # mypy isn't smart enough to figure out that if `init` is 
            # `None`, then `S` is equal to `T`, we therefore need to tell it
            # that this assignment is correct
            acc = cast(T, next(itor)) 
        except StopIteration:
            raise ValueError("fold_left given empty iterable with no init")
    else:
        acc = init

    for i in itor:
        acc = f(acc, i)

    return acc
```

The `overload` statements do help us indirectly, since they restrict the public interface of our function in a way that allows us to reason that the `cast` we use in our implementation is correct.